# Python pip error whenever i try doing anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

Every time i try to do anything with pip or pip3 i get this exact same error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 58
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any clue why?

Comment: f-strings (i.e. `f"..."`) are since python3.6, you are using python3.5 with newer pip. Try `python3.9 -m pip install ...` (or whatever latest version you have installed).

Comment: How do i install the newer versions? I tried apt-get install python3.9, it worked but when i check the version nothing comes up

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/